# Multi GPU training using Pytorch fabric

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I am launching the Pytorch fabric below :

```
fabric = Fabric(accelerator=“cuda”, devices=2, strategy=“auto”, precision=“16-mixed”)
fabric.launch()

model, optimizer = fabric.setup(model, optimizer)
train_loader, val_loader, test_loader = fabric.setup_dataloaders(
        train_loader, val_loader, test_loader
    )
fabric.barrier()
```

I was expecting the model to get trained in a distributed manner on 2 GPUs. But from the output below, the model is getting trained separately on 2 GPUs. I have set for 10 epochs and the model is getting trained separately for 10 epochs on 2 GPUs. Please suggest

```
Epoch: 0001/0010 | Batch 0000/0007 | Batch Train Loss: 0.9700
Epoch: 0001/0010 | Batch 0000/0007 | Batch Train Loss: 0.9700
Epoch: 0001/0010 | Batch 0001/0007 | Batch Train Loss: 0.9626
Epoch: 0001/0010 | Batch 0001/0007 | Batch Train Loss: 0.9626
Epoch: 0001/0010 | Batch 0002/0007 | Batch Train Loss: 0.9524
Epoch: 0001/0010 | Batch 0002/0007 | Batch Train Loss: 0.9524
Epoch: 0001/0010 | Train Loss: 0.9222 | Val Loss: 0.7932
Epoch: 0001/0010 | Train Loss: 0.9222 | Val Loss: 0.7931
```